# Angular-material how to build a sidenav menu that control a md-content?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

i'm developing a mobile based on Angularjs and Angular-Material but i'm a bit confused on how to set up a menu.

here's my semplified situation:

inside of my `body` i have my `md-sidenav` and an `md-content`, inside of my `md-sidenav` there are all the `md-menu-buttons`.

Question: how can i implement those `md-menu-buttons` so that clicking them, a different content is shown in `md-content`.

For example when i click, 'home' a `div` with all the home's stuff appears and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Egxbbw?editors=1010)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" style="height:500px;" ng-cloak="" class="sidenavdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <section layout="row" flex="">
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-whiteframe="4" id="leftSideNav" md-disable-backdrop="true">
      <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo" layout="row">
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button ng-click="close()">Close</md-button>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-content layout-padding="" layout="column" layout-align="start start">
        <md-button ng-click="show('home')" class="md-primary">Show Home</md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="show('work')" class="md-primary">Show Work</md-button>
      </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content flex="" layout-padding="" layout="column" layout-align="top center">
      <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-primary">
        Toggle left
      </md-button>
      <div ng-switch="toShow">
        <div ng-switch-when="home">
          Home!
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="work">
          Work!
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </section>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular
  .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
   $scope.toShow = "home"; // Default

    $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
        $mdSidenav("left")
          .toggle();
    };

    $scope.close = function () {
      $mdSidenav('left').close();
    };

    $scope.show = function (toShow) {
      $scope.toShow = toShow;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably use AngularJS with SPA (*single page application*) concept in mind, so why not make a try with an *AngularJS routing module* - which are particularly built for such purposes.

There are two popular routing modules for AngularJS, namely:

- [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)
- [UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

For the sake of simplicity, you can go with the first one.

Here's how you can set up your routes to display different templates into the `ngView` directive whenever you navigate to a particular route:

### HTML

```
<!-- Your md-buttons -->
<a md-button href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a>
<a md-button href="#some-other-route">Some other route</a>
<!-- ... -->
<md-content>
    <div ng-view></div> <!-- This is where your templates (and their controllers) are injected -->
</md-content>
```

### JS

```
angular.module('yourApp', [
    'ngRoute', 
    // other dependencies
])

.config(function($routeProvider){
    /* 
    * set up your routes here
    */
    $routeProvider.
    when('/dashboard', {
        template: '...'  // alernatively, `templateUrl` if your partial stays somewhere else,
        controller: function (){ 
           /* custom logic for the template */ 
        }
    })
    .when('/some-other-route', {
        template: '...',
        controller: function(){ ... }
    });
})
```

---

## [*Plunker Demo*](https://embed.plnkr.co/BMKUyDLuPIqTfTdiEV7g/)

**Note:** *Do not forget to open the side-nav from the top left if it's not open already in the Plunker demo.*

---

#### Note

Do not forget to load the script for `ngRoute` somewhere after loading angularJS in your HTML.

You may also take a look at [`$locationProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) service's `html5Mode` method for configuring how routes are to work (e.g. `/dashboard` instead of `#dashboard`) in your links.